# QGIS 3.4.11: Viewing issues: Categorised symbology in point layer expands Legend in "Manage Layers Toolbar"

Tags: qgis, layers, style

When I apply categorised symbology to the point layer the legend in Manager Layers Toolbar view expands to the point I cannot see any other layers in the project. This doesn't happen with other types of styling. What could be the cause of this? Is there a way to prevent this behaviour?[image: layer_manager]

Edit: I use QGIS 3.4.11 version - this issue didn't happen in the version 2.18 LTR used previously
I use Simple marker point style with size 1.6 mm. Please see the picture attached for symbology settings.

[image]

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem on QGIS 3.4.3, try restarting QGIS if you haven't already or reinstalling QGIS....

Comment: I've tried reinstalling QGIS, however the problem persists. I also tried disabling all third-party plugins with no change. I wonder whether the fact that my QGIS is installed on virtual server with no graphic card can cause this.